# How can I do audio effects for streaming audio?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, audio-streaming, audiokit

I want to add audio effects such as Delay, Reverb, EQ for streaming audio which comes from internet or local audio file on iOS.

I have found several libraries to add audio effects.
The libraries are AudioKit and AVAudioUnit.
However, I don't understand if these libraries are supporting streaming audio or not.

Can I add audio effects to the streaming audio by using these libraries or other ones ?